# Beginner RoR Git config --global user name error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I am having trouble setting a global user name for git. When I type in git config --global user.name, I get the following error: "fatal: unable to access 'H:/.config/git/config': Invalid argument"

I have created a github account and thought I had made a repository for the project I'm working on, but I am not really sure if I did it right (or if this is related to the issue I am having). Also I get the same error, when I type in git init or git config.

Thanks for any help in advance. If possible, please be detaied as I am learning through tutorials right now. I do have git successfull installed (when I type in git -v I get a version number and ruby and rails are ok as well).

Comment: I have spent time reading up and trying to figure out how to resolve this (including this site http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) but I am not getting it and thought this would be more helpful as I am wasting a bit of time on it.

Comment: do you have an h drive? and is it writeable

Comment: a hard drive? just the one on my laptop (the comp I'm using).  I am not sure if it's writeable; I don't have an external hard drive, just a couple usbs

Comment: sorry h:  it is trying to write to your home Drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting Started with a new Github Account ->

1.) Create a Github Account (You probably done this)

2.) Navigate to your App's Folder (**cd yourfoldername**), you must be in your App's folder to configure git Properties.

```
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"               # Set your Git name
$ git config --global user.email youremail@gmail.com      # Set your Git email
```

3.) Follow these Steps

```
$ git init                          # Set up Git on your project
$ git status                        # See tracked, untracked, and staged files
$ git add .                         # Add new files to Git
$ git commit -am "Initial commit"   # Save your project files to Git
```

4.) Your App is now under Version Controll, now you must Generate your SSH Key.

-> [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

If you are on Windows you can just download the Github Application, it will save you a lot of this Manual Setup. But setting up SSH Key's is not so difficult. Just follow the Guide.

5.) Then, you create a New Repository on Github, and it tells you on Page to enter this 2 lines. Youre Done :)

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com/yourusername/yourreponame.git     # Set up git to push to your Github repository
$ git push -u origin master         # Push your code to Github (sets the upstream the first time)
```

Hope this Helps.

P.S.: I started learning Rails a few weeks ago -> Check this class on skillshare out -> [One Month Rails: Learn to Code](http://skl.sh/YZ8swT) !!

Comment: I am actually using that program! That is the part I'm stuck on! I must not know how to set up the github account (I guess) bc when I type those commands I am still getting errors!

Comment: If you are using the Github Program u don't need any of those commands.
Just navigate to Documents/Github and drop your App folder in there. Then Sync with the github Program

Comment: Hmm...I do not see the github folder...How do I get there? Should I make a new folder mkdir github?

Comment: Just open any folder and on the left Sidebar, under Libraries (Photos, videos, Documents, Music) go into Documents Folder. There should be a Github Folder

Comment: In Your Github Programm, after you Signed in. Press **+Create** and Select where you wish to have Your Synced Github Folder. Then Drop your app in there.

Comment: Sorry - so should I Set up Git or Create Repository?

Comment: No prob :) Log in to the Github Program, and from there u don't need to do anything on the Github Site. Just Specify the folder when you hit **+Create**, Give it a Name and description. And Then just IN THAT folder you specified, drop your App.

Comment: Ok - I'm really sorry. This is the part that I do not quite understand...I have logged into the site..where is the +Create section (I'm using windows btw)

Comment: Am I suppose to download this to my desktop? How do I access the github program? I just did a search on my laptop and did not have files or folders named github. Do I access this in command prompt (i.e. type in "git" command?)

Comment: OK, so I have downloaded the above program; then I logged into the website. Then I did +Create and gave it a name (i have two repositories omrails and omrails2).  How do I drop the app into the specified folder (or what folder?)?

Comment: cool, from there you just log in to the program with your github credentials, press on the top **+create**, Select a folder you want, drop your App in there and Sync :)

Comment: Ok - so I do cd until I'm in the correct folder? THen I do all those git config , git init commands? That doesn't seem to be working. I'm sorry to not be smarter but I have actually used Hart'l tutorial and OMR and still am not really sure what to do

Comment: No no no, if you are using the Github Programm on your PC, you don't need those commands. I learned it too from OMR. Give me your email Address and i will help you through there.

Comment: Hi - I just sent  you another email Mini John

Answer (score 0):

Are you also providing your user name as an argument? It should be `git config --global user.name "User Name"`. Just checking since you didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: Do you mean the username for my github account? I have tried that and putting in other names as well and that same error is showing up...do I need to do something with SSH keys??

Comment: No, the user name you want to give yourself.  Yes, you do need to set up your SSH keys with github.  [Follow the instructions here.](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)